# CSS появились непредвиденные верхние и нижние оступы

Tags: css3

```
.bottom-kit input, 
.bottom-kit button {
    height: 60px;
    border: none;
}

.bottom-kit input {
    background-color: #FFB129;
    border: 2px solid #252322;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.bottom-kit input::placeholder {
    color: #252322;
}

.bottom-kit button {
    border: none;
    color: #f5ecc9;
    background-color: #252322;
    min-width: 289px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
```

[Скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3z76.png)

Comment: они и были эту отступы всегда а что бы бороться с ними обычно их обнуляют т.е пишут *{margin: 0; padding: 0;} это глобальное обнуление отступов, либо это делают для html,body{margin: 0; padding: 0;} только для html и body

Comment: Я сделал обнуление. В инспекторе отступов нет, а визуально button смещен в форме выше инпутов на 1-2px